# Building a daemonized Python application on Linux

Tags: python, linux, daemon

Are there best practices for building a daemonized Python application on Linux?  Something that can either poll for status, or sit and wait for tasks in an event loop?

I have a basic project layout I like to use for command line tools which are called interactively.  But I'm looking to develop a daemon that can sit in a loop polling for certain events, and then act on them.  Specifically, this will run on Red Hat/CentOS, but I'm looking for a general approach to help me get started.

Comment: A http server is similar to what you describe.

Comment: Can you describe a couple of use cases?

Comment: what triggers these events you speak of?

Comment: The service will be a rabbitmq worker.  It will listen for events from a queue and act on them, depending upon the type of event.